# Can you use CSS to animate an image to a random location?

Tags: css, image, animation

So, I don't have any specific code for this project, but is it possible to use CSS and/or CSS Animations to animate an image to a random position? I know it is possible using a JavaScript canvas, but is there a way using just plain CSS? And if so, how? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Hello! How would I go about this? Thanks!

Comment: @ZohirSalak could you include a snippet of code with random position ONLY with CSS please? this is the best I found https://css-tricks.com/are-there-random-numbers-in-css/, but there is not a random() event for CSS, just for SCSS or javascript

Comment: That is the best you can do with just CSS, randomization doesn't exist within css, All you can do is pre-define values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do it by CSS only, but you can do it with SCSS https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math#random.

When the SCSS will be converted in CSS the value will be "static" again.

If you want a dynamic value every time you visit the page you need javascript.

Comment: Thank you! Will try!